# SQL*Plus spool data in HTML format

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, spool

I would like to SPOOL data in SQL*Plus using HTML format. Below is my code

```
SET HEADING ON
SET PAGESIZE 50000
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET MARKUP HTML ON
SPOOL Result_file.html

SELECT *
  FROM Table A;

spool off

exit
```

**Now**

i) It is working fine as long as the result set do not exceed maximum page size (which is 50000).

ii) When result set exceeds maximum page size, it includes headers (repeating header for every page).

I have few tables which exceed page size limit. Do any one know how to achieve that? If any one is using SPOOL to output as .csv file? I have been trying multiple ways but none is giving required results other than HTML format.

Answer (score 0):

Set Pagesize value to zero which will suppress the repeated printing of headers.

```
set pagesize 0
```

Comment: Yes but i need header once in the file. I just do not want repeated headers for every page.

Comment: @H.S  Try **set pagesize 0 embedded on**