# How to format the output in Oracle SQL*Plus?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I am using Oracle SQL*Plus. I get the output in the format below, but I want the title to appear once only, which is at the top. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/53394440/1509264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [use](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b12170/ch7.htm#sthref1395):

```
SET PAGESIZE 50000
```

To change the number of lines on a page (before the headers are repeated).

Or, if you do not want any headers then:

```
SET PAGESIZE 0
```